# RPi Pico and OV2640 using C/C++ SDK

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, c, camera, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to connect an [OV2640](https://www.uctronics.com/download/OV2640_DS.pdf) with RPi Pico using the C++ SDK to get images over UART.

I found [this library](https://github.com/the6p4c/rp2040_ov2640) but I have been on this for days but cant figure out the PIN connection. I tried reading the code and this is what I have till now:-

```
SCL ------------ GPIO5 (1k pull up)
SDA ------------ GPIO4 (1k pull up)
RESETB --------- GPIO2
XCLK ----------- GPIO3
VSYNC ---------- GPIO16
D0 ------------- GPIO6
D1 ------------- GPIO7
D2 ------------- GPIO8
D3 ------------- GPIO9
D4 ------------- GPIO10
D5 ------------- GPIO11
D6 ------------- GPIO12
D7 ------------- GPIO13
PWDN ----------- not sure; I don't think this library uses it
HREFF ---------- no idea what to do with it
```

I'm getting a message saying "received empty command" so I think the communication is working. I think I'm messing up the `D0-D7` and `HREFF` connections.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?